# Input fields showing the same

Tags: html, angularjs

I have problem with input fields in AngularJS. Whatever I write in one, I getting exactly same text in another one (`field_start` = `field_end`). What am I doing wrong? Is it something wrong with `ng-model`?

**template.html**

```
<form name="editForm" role="form" novalidate ng-submit="vm.save()">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"
            ng-click="vm.clear()">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myPackLabel">Create offer</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="field_start">Miejsce startowe</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_start" id="field_start"
             ng-model="vm.transitPointStart.city" placeholder="np. Warszawa"
             />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="field_end">Miejsce docelowe</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_end" id="field_end"
             ng-model="vm.transitPointEnd.city" placeholder="np. Wrocław"
             />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="vm.clear()">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>&nbsp;<span>Cancel</span>
    </button>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="editForm.$invalid || isSaving" class="btn btn-primary">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>&nbsp;<span>Save</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**controller.js**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('AddOfferDialogController', AddOfferDialogController);

  AddOfferDialogController.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$uibModalInstance', 'entity', 'ShipmentOffer', 'TransitPoint', 'PackageSlot'];

  function AddOfferDialogController ($scope, $stateParams, $uibModalInstance, entity, ShipmentOffer, TransitPoint) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.shipmentOffer = entity;
    vm.transitPointStart = entity;
    vm.transitPointEnd = entity;

    vm.save = function () {
      vm.shipmentOffer.date = new Date();
      TransitPoint.save(vm.transitPointStart);
      TransitPoint.save(vm.transitPointEnd);
      ShipmentOffer.save(vm.shipmentOffer);
      $uibModalInstance.close();
      vm.isSaving = false;
    }

    vm.clear = function() {
      $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
  }
})();
```

Comment: It is not a surprise. You populate in both cases the entity.city property. You should make difference between those properties. You need two properties to manage the start city and arrival city.

Comment: Thanks you i get it now, but is it possible to handle it, if i need two different entity.city in same dialog? I cant change my database right now.

Comment: I don't know your db schema, but you have the liberty to modify the data model you have at client level as you want. After that you need to take care of make it fit for your db schema.

Comment: If my answer is correct and you'll accept it then I'll write a proper one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same object in your two references:

```
vm.transitPointStart = entity;
vm.transitPointEnd = entity;
```

maybe you need to create a clone to have different objects in your references (it depends of your requirements):

```
vm.transitPointStart = Object.assign({}, entity);
vm.transitPointEnd = Object.assign({}, entity);
```

Comment: I wish I could, but I am new and I cant :|

Comment: You could also inject `entityStart` and `entityEnd` and then create these two factories to manage your datas

Comment: Oh, now everything is clear, thanks for alternate :)